# Translator : You're going down

Tags: translation, german-to-english, idiom

My father's golf mates use the phrase "you're going down" before the game, meaning you will lose.

He has asked me to translate it to German, but I can't find the correct phrase.

Comment: @c.p. Well, it's hard to find out which of the 100 possible translations would fit the situation Mawg is mentioning, isn't it?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: By remembering, what you have heard before. By looking up the opposite direction of translation. By looking for books which contain the phrase in context and looking up the translation of the book. By creating an idiomatic sentence in the target language and looking for search results with google...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one possible translation, which is almost verbatim, and can be used in sports, for teams as well as for individual competitors, predicting their failure or losing a game:

> Du wirst untergehen!

Informal you is assumed because the phrase by itself is rather informal, too.

Comment: I thought of that, of course, but it isn't very idiomatic :-( Nothing involving beer or sausage? ;-)

Comment: Maybe I can come up with something better, maybe use a different English phrase, like “we’re playing of all the marbles now”, and find a phrase involving beer or sausage :-)

Comment: @Mawg If he wants to certainly use sausage, he can say "Armes Würstchen, du wirst untergehen!"

Comment: @Mawg Sorry, that German does not fulfill your expectations. Even more informal is: *Du wirst eines auf die Mütze kriegen*.

Comment: He he - I like that one :-)  And, German ***does*** fulfill my expectations - normally, which is why I hoped for something colo(u)rful for this one.